Damaged passport?
I have slight staple holes on my passport. Will it be considered slightly damaged passport? I got the visa. I am flying to Japan, but I am worried about immigration or the airlines rejecting it.


That's perfectly normal and acceptable. Passports are "working documents" and some wear and tear is unavoidable.
